# Namespace of Android, Xamarin and XamarinForms not found

Tags: c#, android, git, visual-studio, xamarin

I cloned a Xamarin.Forms project from GitHub and opened it in Visual Studio. There I get 194 errors, because of namespace/usings that are not found.
These usings are red underlined (all except "using System"):

- using Foundation
- using UIKit
- using Android
- using Windows
- using Xamarin

The project should work because my team member who pushed it to git can build it on his pc.
I'm very new in Xamarin.Forms and Visual Studio, so please write a detailed answer. :)
Should I install these namespaces, or why doesn't Visual Studio recognize them?

Comment: Do you have Xamarin installed?

Comment: yes, Xamarin ist installed.

Comment: Double check you have `Mono.Android.dll` referenced in your `Xamarin.Android` project, and `Xamarin.iOS.dll` referenced in your `Xamarin.iOS` project

Comment: Check of your nuget.exe is working as expected.

Comment: where can I check if I have Mono.Android.dll referenced?

Comment: the nuget manager is installed, version  3.4.4 and I can use iti, so I think nuget.exe works.

Comment: "where can I check if I have Mono.Android.dll referenced?" IN the references folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:**
Close VisualStudio

**Step2:**
Go to these root folders:

Mac:

```
Mac: ~/.local/share/Xamarin/   
Mac: ~/.local/share/Xamarin.Android/
```

Windows:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Xamarin\
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android\
```

Delete all the files there. And also clear Temp Folders from you machine

**Step3:**
Go to your project in Visual Studio and close all the tabs from Windows -> Close All Tabs and then click on Build -> Clean Solution and then click on Build -> Rebuild Solution.